# Displaying only labels that are being used?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, data-mining

I am using the following to plot the graph given below:

```
data <- structure(list(Type1 = c("DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", 
"DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "Manual", "Manual", 
"Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", 
"Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual"), 
    Type2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "F", 
    "G", "A", "B", "C", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "O", "J", 
    "P", "K", "Q", "M", "K", "P", "J", "P"), Percent = c("83.5106383", 
    "9.574468085", "5.85106383", "0.531914894", "1/188*100", 
    "85.24590164", "11.47540984", "1/61*100", "1.639344262", 
    "90", "3.333333333", "3.333333333", "3.333333333", "20.10582011", 
    "10.05291005", "6.349206349", "5.82010582", "4.761904762", 
    "31.14754098", "16.39344262", "6.557377049", "6.557377049", 
    "4.918032787", "30", "23.33333333", "16.66666667", "10", 
    "6.666666667")), .Names = c("Type1", "Type2", "Category", 
"Percent"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")

data$Percent <- as.numeric(data$Percent)

g= ggplot(data, aes(x=Category, y=Percent)) + 
          geom_bar(width=0.8, stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
          facet_grid(Type1 ~ Type2, ) + 
          theme_bw() + 
          coord_flip() + 
          scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100))

print(g)
```

[image]

Is there any way that I can make the plot such taht each row uses only the labels that non-zero? For instance, take the `DB` row. It uses only 6 labels but displays all the 16 labels because the other 10 are being used by the `Manual` part of the data. Likewise for the `Manual` row. What I am looking for is something like this:

```
        1            2             3
H
G
D                                        DB
C
B
A

Q
P
O
G                                        MANUAL
M
L
K
J
I
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I played around with this for a bit (after i fixed the issues in your example data) and I'm beginning to think there may be some issues with facet_grid and the scales argument. However, you could also use facet_wrap instead, and that appears to work.

Comment: @joran: +1 Thank you for your time. I played around too and I can confirm that there is a bug. I will report it sometime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug or unexpected behavior when combining `facet_grid(scales="free")` and `coord_flip()`.

Here are 2 possible work-arounds:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Removed quotes from Percent values, so that Percent will be numeric.
dat <- structure(list(Type1 = c("DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", 
"DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "DB", "Manual", "Manual", 
"Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", 
"Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual"), 
    Type2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "F", 
    "G", "A", "B", "C", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "O", "J", 
    "P", "K", "Q", "M", "K", "P", "J", "P"), Percent = c(83.5106383, 
    9.574468085, 5.85106383, 0.531914894, 1/188*100, 
    85.24590164, 11.47540984, 1/61*100, 1.639344262, 
    90, 3.333333333, 3.333333333, 3.333333333, 20.10582011, 
    10.05291005, 6.349206349, 5.82010582, 4.761904762, 
    31.14754098, 16.39344262, 6.557377049, 6.557377049, 
    4.918032787, 30, 23.33333333, 16.66666667, 10, 
    6.666666667)), .Names = c("Type1", "Type2", "Category", 
"Percent"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")

figure_1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=Category, y=Percent)) + 
           geom_bar(width=0.8, stat="identity") + 
           facet_grid(Type2 ~ Type1, scales="free_x") + 
           theme_bw() + 
           scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100)) +
           opts(title="Figure 1. Success!\n(But Rotated 90 Degrees)")

figure_2 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=Percent, y=Category)) + 
           geom_point(size=3) + 
           facet_grid(Type1 ~ Type2, scales="free_y") + 
           theme_bw() + 
           scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 100)) +
           opts(title="Figure 2. Success!\n(But Dotplot Instead Of Barplot)")

# Unexpected interaction between scales="free" and coord_flip()?
figure_3 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=Category, y=Percent)) + 
           geom_bar(width=0.8, stat="identity") + 
           facet_grid(Type1 ~ Type2, scales="free") + 
           theme_bw() + 
           scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100)) +
           coord_flip() +
           opts(title="Figure 3. Strange Y-axis Behavior.")
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It will only remove those elements that are not in ANY of the facets. But you can use the scales="free" argument in facet_grid().

```
g + facet_grid(Type1 ~ Type2, scales="free")
```

But I think a facet_wrap, might provide you with a more appropriate visualization:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Category, y=Percent)) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.8, stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(Type1 ~ Type2,scales="free") + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(c(0,100)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  opts()
```

[image]